# Compiling driver for raspbian jessie 4.4.21-v7+

Tags: linux, driver, modules, software-compilation

I'm trying to compile the driver of rtl8812AU (github.com/diederikdehaas/rtl8812AU).
I've downloaded and installed the last version of raspbian.

The following is written in the change log, among others:
2016-09-23:
* Updated firmware and kernel (github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/commit/ad8608c08b122b2c228dba0ff5070d6e9519faf5)

I know I need the headers of the kernel to compile the module:

> mkdir /usr/src/firmware && cd /usr/src/firmware
>   git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware
>   git checkout ad8608c08b122b2c228dba0ff5070d6e9519faf5
>   cat /usr/src/firmware/git_hash

which gives me 2d31cd571e6f2ac61a3eda273d973058e1bb1f58

> mkdir /usr/src/linux && cd /usr/src/linux
>   git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
>   git checkout 2d31cd571e6f2ac61a3eda273d973058e1bb1f58

Now I'm not sure how to proceed anymore. I've tried building the module with DKMS but I couldn't manage to let 'dkms build' pass the right ARCH to 'make'. It executes 'make ARCH=armv7l', but there's no folder /usr/src/linux/arch/armv7l. It should be looking into /usr/src/linux/arch/arm. [I've asked a question on stack overflow about this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775844/how-to-make-dkms-pass-the-right-arch-to-make)

Since DKMS is not on my side now want to build the module by evoking 'make' directly. So now I executed:

> **sudo make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.21-v7+/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU/4.3.14/build  modules**
>
> make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux'
>
> ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
>            include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
>            Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
>
> WARNING: Symbol version dump ./Module.symvers
>              is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.
>
> Building modules, stage 2.   scripts/Makefile.modpost:42:
>   include/config/auto.conf: No such file or directory

How to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try running "make oldconfig && make prepare" as suggested? That generates auto.conf as your failure message indicates.